# 2d list not working

Tags: python, list, grid

I am trying to create a 2D list, and I keep getting the same error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"  I do not understand why, or how to use a 2D list correctly.

```
Total = 0
server = xmlrpclib.Server(url);
mainview = server.download_list("", "main")
info = [[]]
info[0,0] = hostname
info[0,1] = time
info[0,2] = complete
info[0,3] = Errors
for t in mainview:
  Total += 1
  print server.d.get_hash(t)
  info[Total, 0] = server.d.get_hash(t)
  info[Total, 1] = server.d.get_name(t)
  info[Total, 2] = server.d.complete(t)
  info[Total, 3] = server.d.message(t)

  if server.d.complete(t) == 1:
    Complete += 1
  else:
    Incomplete += 1
  if (str(server.d.message(t)).__len__() >= 3):
    Error += 1
info[0,2] = Complete
info[0,3] = Error
```

everything works, except for trying to deal with info.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "2d list" in Python.  What you have is a list whose contents are also lists.  If you think about what this means you'll understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in accessing the 2D-list, modify:

```
info[0,0] = hostname
info[0,1] = time
info[0,2] = complete
info[0,3] = Errors
```

to:

```
info[0].append(hostname)
info[0].append(time)
info[0].append(complete)
info[0].append(Errors)
```

Same goes to `info[Total, 0]` and etc.

Comment: this will still cause errors since the list is empty to begin with, ie list index out of range error

Answer (score 1):

The way you created `info`, it is a list containing only one element, namely an empty list. When working with lists, you have to address the nested items like

```
info[0][0] = hostname
```

For initialization, you have to create a list of lists by e.g.

```
# create list of lists of 0, size is 10x10
info = [[0]*10 for i in range(10)]
```

When using `numpy` arrays, you can address the elements as you did.

One advantage of "lists of lists" is that not all entries of the "2D list" shall have the same data type!

Answer (score -1):

```
info = [[] for i in range(4)] # create 4 empty lists inside a list
info[0][0].append(hostname)
info[0][1].append(time)
info[0][2].append(complete)
info[0][3].append(Errors)
```

You need to create the 2d array first.

Comment: thats not how you call elements in a list of lists